# "God is us" versus "God is we"

Tags: syntax

Which one is syntactically correct and why?

> God is us.

> God is we.

Comment: Um.. neither of those is correct.

Comment: What are you trying to say, exactly? What would the context be?

Comment: i want to establish a new religion ;D i want to say that god is us and we are god.

Comment: You could say that, and people would know what you mean, although I do not think that it is proper. I would probably say "We are equivalent to God."

Comment: i mean something like that god is (created from the sum of) all of us. albeit i just joked about new religion. it's only some imagination (at least so far :) )

Comment: So say exactly what you just said. "God is the sum total of all of us."

Comment: oh i want some poetry!

Comment: So say "God is us." I don't think it's proper, but people will understand you.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to say that, then say *God is **us***, not *God is **we***.

You can say:

> God is **with us**.
>   God is **for us**.
>   God is **all around us**.

But if you want to reverse the sentences, you must change **us** to **We**, which you already know.

Delete the preposition and make **us** the subject complement as in:

> God is **us**.
>   ***We*** are the X people but *The X people are **us***.

Why do you think the name of the chain store is *Toy R **Us*** and not *Toys R **We***? Because *Toys R **Us*** is normal, natural, idiomatic spoken English and *Toys R **We*** is stilted.

> A: Who's there?
>   B: It's **me**, your son.
>   or
>   C: It's **us**, the Robinsons.

Say *It is **I**, your son* or *It is **we**, the Robinsons*, and native Anglophones will wonder why you're hypercorrecting. Okay, my 89-year-old English-teacher stepmother says *It is I*, but she also says **whom** a lot.

Grammaticality is not a reasonable criterion for choosing a slogan or a sales pitch. You've gotta hit people where they live and know how to press the right emotional buttons. Use stilted language and people will laugh at you for being a pretentious snob.

Look at the modern world's great painters: Chagall, Picasso, Van Gogh. The colors and shapes they used for people and animals aren't *correct*. they're creative, artistic, beautiful.

**Say what sounds good, not what sounds correct. Then people will listen.** That's always been the rule.

Comment: It has always bothered me that the store was called "Toys R Us" instead of "We."

Comment: @Daniel: You must've been born at the same time as my stepmother. She's from Ohio & Indiana. People there talk funny. I'm from NJ & NYC. :-)

Comment: Doubt it. I was born in 1990 :)  I'm from Wisconsin though. Maybe we just maintined proper grammar here in the midwest.

Comment: How about *We R Toys*? ;)

Comment: @Wendi: It's a matter of focus. They sell **toys**, not _we_ & not _us_. Where does a toy store want to be listed in the phone book, under T for toys or W for we? The _Winston tastes good, **like** a cigarette should_ ad proved how effective advertising that flouted grammatical rules was. Now the food clown avers "**I'm lovin' it!**" every chance it gets, & billions of idiots mindlessly chant that & _Just do it!_ & _Go for it!_. _Catchy_, not _meaningful_ or _correct_, is effective. What works is good; what fails is forgotten. My language is formal, not ad-speak: I don't write ads. Pragmatic.